# Remove duplicated data complex sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following complex query

```
SELECT TOP 20
    [image].Image_id, Source_Link
FROM 
    Item
INNER JOIN 
    [Image] ON Item.Image_id = [Image].Image_id
INNER JOIN 
    Age_Item ON Item.Item_id = Age_Item.Item_id
WHERE 
    Gender = 'male'
    AND Age_Item.Age_id = 4
    AND [Image].Image_id NOT IN
        (SELECT [Image].Image_id
         FROM [Image]
         INNER JOIN Item on [Image].Image_id = Item.Image_id
         INNER JOIN Session_Item on Item.Item_id = Session_Item.Item_id
         WHERE Session_Item.Session_id = 3)
ORDER BY 
    NEWID() -- random rows
```

however, I realized that sometimes it shows some duplicated results and I wanted to remove the duplicated rows

I tried `SELECT DISTINCT` but it shows this error :

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

and I can't use `GROUP BY([Image].Image_id)` in this case because the column `[Image].Source_Link` is not contained in an aggregate function.

What should I do to fix this issue?

//EDIT:
I've fixed it that way, thanks for your answers guys

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT [image].Image_id, Source_Link
FROM Item
INNER JOIN [Image] ON Item.Image_id = [Image].Image_id
INNER JOIN Age_Item ON Item.Item_id = Age_Item.Item_id
WHERE Gender='male'
AND Age_Item.Age_id = 4
AND [Image].Image_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT [Image].Image_id
    FROM [Image]
    INNER JOIN Item on [Image].Image_id = Item.Image_id
    INNER JOIN Session_Item on Item.Item_id = Session_Item.Item_id
    WHERE Session_Item.Session_id = 3
)
)query ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Comment: Do you have an example of duplicated rows?

Comment: yeah, for example these are the results for my last test:
48 ~/Items/194871b0-9bab-49d5-95d7-6c7fa7f02177.jpg |
73 ~/Items/1f7353f9-d922-4eb3-a90b-b33c2f2d864e.jpg |
87 ~/Items/72aae055-7a10-4fd8-99a3-0558dcfa2d26.jpg |
84 ~/Items/d50db98b-8ad1-4171-b9c1-5847cbd4b195.jpg |
84 ~/Items/d50db98b-8ad1-4171-b9c1-5847cbd4b195.jpg |
...
notice that the row of id 84 is duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a random 20 distinct and order randomly you'll need to get a distinct set and then apply your `TOP 20` `ORDER BY NEW_ID` after.

You can do that with a CTE

```
with cte as (

SELECT DISTINCT [image].Image_id, Source_Link
FROM Item
INNER JOIN [Image] ON Item.Image_id = [Image].Image_id
INNER JOIN Age_Item ON Item.Item_id = Age_Item.Item_id
WHERE Gender='male'
AND Age_Item.Age_id = 4
AND [Image].Image_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT [Image].Image_id
    FROM [Image]
    INNER JOIN Item on [Image].Image_id = Item.Image_id
    INNER JOIN Session_Item on Item.Item_id = Session_Item.Item_id
    WHERE Session_Item.Session_id = 3
)
)
Select TOP 20 DISTINCT * FROM CTE ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: I got this error >>

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @AboudZakaria forgot the keyword `as` between CTE and the (

Comment: aha got it, it worked like a charm thanks.
the only problem now that the rows are ordered by Image_id again

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ( <your original query> ) query;
```

I just tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
SELECT TOP 20 [image].Image_id, Source_Link
FROM Item
INNER JOIN [Image] ON Item.Image_id = [Image].Image_id
INNER JOIN Age_Item ON Item.Item_id = Age_Item.Item_id
WHERE Gender='male'
AND Age_Item.Age_id = 4
AND [Image].Image_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT [Image].Image_id
    FROM [Image]
    INNER JOIN Item on [Image].Image_id = Item.Image_id
    INNER JOIN Session_Item on Item.Item_id = Session_Item.Item_id
    WHERE Session_Item.Session_id = 3
)
ORDER BY NEWID()) query;
```

...and it compiled fine for me.

Comment: I tried this but it shows this error
Incorrect syntax near ')'. the last arc

Comment: sorry my bad, I forgot the add the word query in the end. it works yeah, but there's still a problem, rows are ordered by Image_id again..